# C# get default application for file type

Tags: c#, file, interop

I'm using this code to get the default application for file types like ".txt".
It works completely fine but why do I have to call the same method two times? The only thing I found out is, that the `lenth` is set after the first call. But do I really have to execute the function twice because I need the length first?

If I execute it only once, it crashes.

**CODE**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint AssocQueryString(
    AssocF flags, 
    AssocStr str,  
    string pszAssoc, 
    string pszExtra, 
    [Out] StringBuilder pszOut, 
    ref uint pcchOut
); 
[Flags]
public enum AssocF
{
    None = 0,
    Init_NoRemapCLSID = 0x1,
    Init_ByExeName = 0x2,
    Open_ByExeName = 0x2,
    Init_DefaultToStar = 0x4,
    Init_DefaultToFolder = 0x8,
    NoUserSettings = 0x10,
    NoTruncate = 0x20,
    Verify = 0x40,
    RemapRunDll = 0x80,
    NoFixUps = 0x100,
    IgnoreBaseClass = 0x200,
    Init_IgnoreUnknown = 0x400,
    Init_Fixed_ProgId = 0x800,
    Is_Protocol = 0x1000,
    Init_For_File = 0x2000
}
public enum AssocStr
{
    Command = 1,
    Executable,
    FriendlyDocName,
    FriendlyAppName,
    NoOpen,
    ShellNewValue,
    DDECommand,
    DDEIfExec,
    DDEApplication,
    DDETopic,
    InfoTip,
    QuickTip,
    TileInfo,
    ContentType,
    DefaultIcon,
    ShellExtension,
    DropTarget,
    DelegateExecute,
    Supported_Uri_Protocols,
    ProgID,
    AppID,
    AppPublisher,
    AppIconReference,
    Max
}
```

**SAMPLE USAGE:**

```
static string AssocQueryString(AssocStr association, string extension)
    {
        const int S_OK = 0;
        const int S_FALSE = 1;

        uint length = 0;
        uint ret = AssocQueryString(AssocF.None, association, extension, null, null, ref length);
        if (ret != S_FALSE)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not determine associated string");
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder((int)length); // (length-1) will probably work too as the marshaller adds null termination
        ret = AssocQueryString(AssocF.None, association, extension, null, sb, ref length);
        if (ret != S_OK)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not determine associated string"); 
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You could also guess a length that will probably be sufficient. But what is the problem with calling it twice?

Comment: I seems a little "dirty" to me, but if it's necessary i'll leave it like this. I think it's kinda weird that the method needs the length, why can't it just save the value in a string or sth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AssocQueryString** is a WinAPI function. This is a kind of system-level general-purpose function, which might be used in different kinds of applications. Using applications might happen to have VERY tight performance and/or memory requirements. That's why WinAPI functions never do memory allocations themselves (as memory allocation might be a relatively expensive task performance-wise), they expect all the required memory to be provided to them by the caller.

In many cases (like with this **AssocQueryString** functionality) one can not know the required amount of memory before the function execution. Here the API developers "merged" two functions into one: if you call **AssocQueryString** with null instead of output string it will calculate you the required string length, otherwise it will use the string you've provided expecting that you've already allocated enough memory for that string.

You don't need to worry about calling the function twice. In fact, you're calling two slightly different functions: one is to calculate the required string length and another is to actually do the job (i.e. search the registry for a file association).